# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToOne.orphanRemoval()Z

Tags: java, hibernate

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToOne.orphanRemoval()Z
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1613) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:765) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:684) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3437) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3391) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1341) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1733) ~[?:?]
        at dk.simonwinther.MainPlugin.saveData(MainPlugin.java:114) ~[?:?]
        at dk.simonwinther.MainPlugin.onDisable(MainPlugin.java:103) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:323) ~[server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.disablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:364) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:424) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:417) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.clearPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:458) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:708) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:535) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:641) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1162) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:997) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:45) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_281]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_281]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:44) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:715) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:374) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557) [server.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_281]
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dk</groupId>
    <artifactId>simonwinther</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BandePlugin</name>

    <description>Et avanceret bande plugin</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <url>simon-winther.dk</url>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
         </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sk89q-repo</id>
            <url>https://maven.enginehub.org/repo/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>everything</id>
            <url>https://repo.citizensnpcs.co</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q.worldguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldguard-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q.worldedit</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldedit-bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.MilkBowl</groupId>
            <artifactId>VaultAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.citizensnpcs</groupId>
            <artifactId>citizens</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.27-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Gang.java**

```
    public Gang(int gangId, String gangName, UUID ownerUuid)
    {
        this.gangId = gangId;
        this.gangName = gangName;
        membersSorted.put(ownerUuid, Rank.LEADER.getValue());
    }

    public Gang() {

    }

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false) private String gangName = "";
    @Id @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false) private int gangId;
    @Column(name = "Balance", nullable = false) private int gangBalance = 100;
    @Column(name = "Level", nullable = false) private int gangLevel = 1;
    @Column(name = "MaxMembers", nullable = false) private int maxMembers = 3;
    @Column(name = "MaxAllies", nullable = false) private int maxAllies = 2;
    @Column(name = "MaxEnemies", nullable = false) private int maxEnemies = 3;
    @Column(name = "GangDamage", nullable = false) private int gangDamage = 100;
    @Column(name = "AllyDamage", nullable = false) private int allyDamage = 100;
    @Column(name = "GKills", nullable = false) private int guardKills = 0;
    @Column(name = "PKills", nullable = false) private int prisonerKills = 0;
    @Column(name = "OKills", nullable = false) private int officerKills = 0;
    @Column(name = "Deaths", nullable = false) private int deaths = 0;
    @Column(name = "NameChanged", nullable = false) private boolean nameBeenChanged = false;


------------
Without this code below, the code works PERFECT.

    @OneToOne
    public GangPermissions gangPermissions = new GangPermissions(this.gangId);
```

**GangPermissions.java**

```
package dk.simonwinther;

import dk.simonwinther.constants.Rank;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
public class GangPermissions implements Serializable
{

    @Transient private final long serialVersionUID = 98798793217321L;

    public GangPermissions(int gangID){
        this.gangID = gangID;
    }

    public GangPermissions(){

    }

    @Id private int gangID;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Rank accessToGangShop = Rank.CO_LEADER
            , accessToTransferMoney = Rank.OFFICER
            , accessToTransferItems = Rank.OFFICER
            , accessToKick = Rank.LEADER
            , accessToDeposit = Rank.MEMBER
            , accessToEnemy = Rank.OFFICER
            , accessToAlly = Rank.OFFICER
            , accessToInvite = Rank.CO_LEADER
            , accessToLevelUp = Rank.CO_LEADER
            , accessToGangChat = Rank.MEMBER
            , accessToAllyChat = Rank.OFFICER;

    @Column(name="AccessToToilet")
    public boolean accessToToilets = false;
    @Column(name="AccessToFarm")
    public boolean accessToFarm = false;
    @Column(name="AccessToLab")
    public boolean accessToLab = false;
}
```

I have looked for hours, literally. I've seen multiple people cover this on StackOverflow, and they all say it's because I have two versions of the JPA persistence, or I should replace javax.persistence 1.0 with JPA 2.0, but at this point I have no clue more. I tried 3 different discords too, no one could help, so now I'm trying to do it on here...

Comment: As you indicated, the problem has to do with a mismatch in the JPA version: that method is available only since JPA 2.0. Please, can you include the following dependency in your `pom.xml` and see if it works? `<dependency>     <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>     <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>     <version>1.0.2.Final</version> </dependency>`

Comment: Although probably unrelate, be aware that you are using a quite dated version of hibernate as well: try a more recent version of the `4.x` branch, like `4.3.11.Final`, or even the more recent `5.4.29.Final`

Comment: Didn't work
Stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/UtujCNAb
Pom.xml: https://pastebin.com/UiXu94Df

Comment: I think it's because I need to unload JPA 1 so it loads JPA 2 instead, but I have no clue how to unload JPA 1???

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ocAGT20
Is this useful for you to see?

Comment: It is fine @Techniko. And, is there in the dependency tree any reference to a different version of JPA in addition to `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` `1.0.2.Final`?

Comment: Sorry, I might sound stupid, but where do you see the dependency tree?

Comment: wait think i found it https://imgur.com/a/XZZlMq0

Comment: Please, include this, I think every should work fine: `<dependency>
  <groupId>org.avaje</groupId>
  <artifactId>ebean</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>`

Comment: 0:01:41 ERROR]: Error occurred while disabling BandePlugin v1.0-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToOne.orphanRemoval()Z

Same error :/

Comment: Please, can you verify if the dependency is still there? Perhaps whether Intellij or maven are not cleaning the old library. Can you verify it in your `target` directory?

Comment: Well were I supposed to exclude it?
imgur.com/a/XZZlMq0
Because the ebean was added I just checked

Comment: Yes, if you review the second dependency I told you to include, it provides an exclusion for the JPA 1.0 API. Please, can you check your dependency tree again in order to verify if the artifact you surrounded in color before is not there anymore?

Comment: This is dependency tree: https://imgur.com/a/K3ijJzU (Scroll down, 3 images)

My updated pom.xml file: https://pastebin.com/eqMcHe0s

Comment: Everything looks fine now. Please, can you verify if the old persistence jar (persistence-api-xx.jar) is in your target directory? It should not.

Comment: I don't think so..
```<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```
Only from this code
But still gets the error....

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I see. I am sorry to hear that the error is still there... Perhaps there is another dependency with JPA 1.0. Please, in any case, verify that IntelliJ is not caching the artifacts, maybe reloading the maven project or performing a clean build.

Comment: You don't have to say sorry for that, you spend your precious time helping me, which you aren't obligated to do, so thank you for not giving up yet on this, and still helping!  
  
I have found a very good picture of my [dependency tree.](https://imgur.com/a/D7vZ7GV)

Comment: Thank you @Techniko :). Thank you for the image as well, yes, it is a very good picture indeed. Please, can you try with a different version of Hibernate, say `4.3.11.Final`. According to the Hibernate releases [information](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/), it supports the provided new JPA jar version since `4.3+`. Please, can you try? In addition, please, try to reimport your maven project, select your `pom.xml` > right click > reimport project. It will refresh all your maven dependencies: perhaps IntelliJ is caching some library.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/S6pBMUqf
This is my pom.xml file and I'm currently already using the version that you're mentioning.:/
Could I possibly add you on Discord or something so make it a bit easier to chat and maybe for you to help? If no, that's totally okay and I respect it.

Comment: Hi @Techniko. I am so sorry, I will try to help you in any way I can, but I prefer not to contact anyone in private. I hope you understand. If you consider it necessary, we can start a chat here, in SO, to make the conversation more dynamic. Please, see [this issue](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/cannot-use-hibernate-orm-because-of-outdated-persistence-api.292749/), especially the last comment: maybe the JPA 1.0 classes are embedded in the spigot jar? It seems to be using the shade plugin, so maybe the classes are embedded in the jar. Please, can you verify it?

Comment: Of course, I understand. I actually did remove dependency from spigot, because spigot does import the JPA 1.0, but I excluded it.
As you can see I do it here: https://pastebin.com/jbVqD9R3

Comment: Thank you very much @Techniko. You are using the shade plugin as well: please, can you see in the generated uber jar if any of the JPA 2.1 classes are included? Search for `java.persistence.EntityGraph` for instance. Is the .class for this interface in your jar?

Comment: How would I check the uber jar? Sorry :/

Comment: This is the tree btw, which is way better than the other ones.. [tree](https://pastebin.com/TjZsTwqv)

Comment: Please, there is no need to say sorry. When you use the maven `shade` plugin, typically when you `package` your application, it will generate a big jar with all your libraries and dependencies included in it. Try to find the indicated class and see if it is there. On the other hand, the tree looks fine. Honestly, I am running out of ideas, in my opinion everything looks fine. The only reason that come to my mind is that one of the jars internally contains the ol `javax.persistence` classes. Please, be sure as well that Intellij is not caching anything. Cut and paste, if necessary, your target

Comment: directory in order to preserve it but at the same time provide a clean space to work with.